# Sending SMS in Android

Tags: android, sms

I am using the below code to send SMS to an Android mobile. But if I send the [SMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS) to any number it's not being sent. What could be the issue?

```
package SMSApp.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMS extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button btnSendSMS;
    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)
                    sendSMS(phoneNo, message);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            /*private void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String message) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(SMS.this, 0, new Intent(SMS.this, SMS.class), 0);
                    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, pi, null);
            }*/

            private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
            {
                String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
                String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

                PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SMS.this, 0,
                    new Intent(SENT), 0);

                PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SMS.this, 0,
                    new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

                //---when the SMS has been sent---
                registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                        switch (getResultCode())
                        {
                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

                //---when the SMS has been delivered---
                registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                        switch (getResultCode())
                        {
                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 12):

I really don't get why would you nest the sendSMS method anyway - the code works for me. Try checking if you got the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

permission set in your file and try this code instead:

```
package SMSApp.com;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMS extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button btnSendSMS;
    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)
                    sendSMS(phoneNo, message);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                   "Please enter both phone number and message.",
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
    }

    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SMS.this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SMS.this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //--- When the SMS has been sent ---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(SMS.this, "SMS sent",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(SMS.this, "Generic failure",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(SMS.this, "No service",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(SMS.this, "Null PDU",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //--- When the SMS has been delivered. ---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(SMS.this, "SMS delivered",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(SMS.this, "SMS not delivered",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to unregister the receiver?

Answer (score 0):

If everything is fine (code, permissions in the manifest file), open two emulator windows (they will be something like **5554:TestDevice1** and **5556:TestDevice1**).

Now, if you are installing your application to 5554, send a message to 5556 and check in another emulator.